# Python Panda's combine mutiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
      id diff
0      abc123      718.0
1      DEF567      679.0
2      HIK445    1567.04
3      abc123      766.6
4      abc123    2307.88
```

how do I concat all the diff's together in a single row separated by (|) byID ?

also I need to add this single new column as a new diff-merged column

Comment: `df.astype(str).groupby('id')['diff'].agg('|'.join)
`

Comment: how about if I wanted it to be a new column name ?

Comment: `df.astype(str).groupby('id')['diff'].agg('|'.join).to_frame('newname').reset_index()
`